# Can't start Ionic getting "Object(..) is not a function"

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've just cloned a repo with some Ionic code, installed ionic 3, npm install and runned the app with ionic serve -c. This is the error that shows when I try to access the app on the browser.

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59675:108
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:59681:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.596 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9282:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at Object.591 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:9265:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:55:30)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:26:23)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1:1



Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0
Angular Core: 5.0.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.1
Node: 11.2.0
OS Platform: Linux 5.3
Navigator Platform: Linux x86_64
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you provide project Github link if its public repo?

Comment: No I can't. It's a private repository Srry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manged to get it to work. There was a problem with the version of agm/core

I've changed the version to "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7". Previously the version was "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3"